# Sync Amazon RDS (PostgreSQL) to S3 in near real time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, synchronization, amazon-rds

I'm wondering whether it is possible to easily sync an Amazon RDS PostgreSQL database to Amazon S3 in near real time so that data can be used with Amazon Athena, just as read replicas do.

We have several RDS database and we would like to consolidate all the data in a single repository such as S3.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need all the data in a central repository "in real time"? Will the queries be requiring the 'latest' information, or can they be satisfied with nightly updates? For examples, sales reports typically want historical information and don't need the very latest data.

Comment: We'd like to build a partner portal / dahsboard to summarize information generated by several microservices. Maybe we do not need "real time" but we'd like to update the information every 10-30 min without decreasing service performance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no capability to "export RDS to S3 in real time".

However, Amazon Athena can query Amazon RDS databases, so you could have some of your data in Amazon S3 and some in Amazon RDS.

See: [Query any data source with Amazon Athena’s new federated query | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/query-any-data-source-with-amazon-athenas-new-federated-query/)

What you are describing sounds like a data warehouse, where information is extracted from many information sources and is stored in one place for easy querying -- often in 'wide' tables to make querying simpler. However, this is very difficult to do "in real time". It is typically updated nightly, or perhaps hourly.

Comment: What you mentions souds good. Maybe we can generate in S3 "historical tables" every night and add the latest information directly from the service database or a read replica.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using AWS Database Migration Service to continuously sync data between RDS and S3: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-dms-target/

saying this, it is only sensible when you don't have a read-only replica of the data and the queries might affect source RDS performance.

Comment: I explored a little this option too, it appends records indicating the operation done to every primary key. For instance row 1: Insert, pk=2, value=3, and row2: Update, pk=2, value=4. Thus you still need a transformation to get the latest state of all records based on indiviudal historical transactions.